# How can I adapt this code to work on Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, web

I'm currently trying to develop a random redirect button and I need to make two adjustments to the following code:

```
<script>
<!--
/*
Random link button- By JavaScript Kit (http://javascriptkit.com)
Over 300+ free scripts!
This credit MUST stay intact for use
*/

//specify random links below. You can have as many as you want
var randomlinks=new Array()

randomlinks[0]="http://surveymonkey.com"
randomlinks[1]="http://typeform.com"
randomlinks[2]="http://dynamicdrive.com"
randomlinks[3]="http://cnn.com"
randomlinks[4]="http://www.geocities.com"

function randomlink(){
window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
}
//-->
</script>
<form method="post">
<p><input type="button" name="B1" value="Continue" onclick="randomlink()"></p> </form>
```

The above code produces a button which appears to do nothing on clicking it on the published website. How can I make the button *actually* redirect? I'd also like to resize the button to be 5x larger and centre aligned.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error appear in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: It works for me here https://jsfiddle.net/9doowg0a/2/

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it won't open, was the `.open` method used in your function.

Here is the new code utilizing `window.open`:

```
window.open(randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]);
```

For formatting the button you should use CSS.

Check out something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tmanti/48Lsdfgh/7/)